# Working with multiple tables and assigning values to array in controller and displaying in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I have a few chunks of codes which are badly written. I don't know how I should go about doing this.

Firstly there's a link which works fine:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', bidders_assignments_path(:assignment_id => assignment.id), :method => :post %></td>
```

That will link to the method bidders in assignment_controller:

```
def bidders
  @bids = Bid.where(bidders_params).find_each
  #I suspect there's error in the lines below
  @bids.each do |bid|
    @bidders = User.where(user.id => bid.user_id).find_each
  end
end

def bidders_params
  params.permit(:assignment_id)
end
```

Once the @bidders array is filled with data, it will be listed on the view:

```
<% @bidders.each do |bidder| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= bidder.gender %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.experience %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.expected_salary %></td>
    <td><%= bidder.education_id %></td>
<% end %>
```

I suspect the error is in the filling of @bidders array with data but I can't be sure that's why I'm here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the error? I suspect it's this `@bids = Bid.where(bidders_params).find_each` because it should be passed a block

Comment: @j-dexx I changed the def bidders as per Arup Rakshit's suggestion to:  
`def bidders  
    bidders_ids = Bid.where(bidders_params).pluck(:user_id)  
    @bidders = User.where(id: bidders_ids)  
  end`    

Now there's no error but no data get displayed. There's no issue with :    

`@bids = Bid.where(bidders_params).find_each`    

The issue is the line after I believe.

Comment: How are you determining there is no issue?  Could it be that there is simply no data in the database matching the passed arguments?

Comment: @j-dexx There is data in the database. I've checked that already. Could it be my way of assigning values to the array @bidders?

Comment: bidders_ids is an array of :user_id and for each of the bidders_ids, there's name of bidders, contact number, and more. So @bidders has got to be a multidimensional array. I just don't know if there's a syntax error in assigning values to the array or displaying the array.

Comment: In your code you redefine `@bidders` on each loop. Arup's code should work, and is more efficient than yours

Comment: @j-dexx Right, I am using Arup's code now. There's no error message but there's no records shown either.

Comment: @j-dexx I tried placing the `def bidders` in the application_controller.rb instead of assignment_controller.rb and it worked. Somehow the function could only access the assignment model when it is placed in the assignment_controller.rb file. So when I move `def bidders` to application_controller.rb it could call all the necessary model and run the could. That's just my guess. Can someone please verify. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an SQL `IN` query. That will fix your code:

```
def bidders
  bid_ids = Bid.where(bidders_params).pluck(:user_id)
  @bidders = User.where(id: bid_ids)
end
```

Use *instance variables* to expose data from controller to *view*. If you need a variable to do some temporary calculations use local variables.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think that's the error. I think the issue is with the `<% @bidders.each do |bidder| %>` part

Comment: I think I didn't declare the array bidders properly. There could be no data inside bidders.